Flutter suddenly undetectable
I tried to open the flutter project but flutter suddenly did not read, I tried flutter doctor and flutter --version, but all that appeared was a command line pop up and closed immediately.
command prompt that appears and closes suddenly
I have tried to download the new stable version of flutter and change the path to the system environment, then delete the cache folder in the flutter/bin directory, after that flutter can be used, but after exiting the command prompt or restarting the pc, flutter is not detected again.
